# Backbone TODO model --> save method

Tags: backbone.js

I am following the annotated source code at:

http://backbonejs.org/docs/todos.html

The model is:

```
var Todo = Backbone.Model.extend({

 defaults: function() {
  return {
    title: "empty todo...",
    order: Todos.nextOrder(),
    done: false
  };
 },
 toggle: function() {
   this.save({done: !this.get("done")});
 }

});
```

My question is:

What happens when this.save is called? I know that the collection uses local storage, but how does the model by itself work?

Answer (score 1):

Model has a [**url** & **urlRoot**](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-urlRoot) methods where you define the Rest end point to your server.

So it will try to connect to that point and execute the code that corresponds to that particular point.  So this saves the new state of the model to your Server.

But because in the case you are referring to , Local storage adapter is used , the changes will be persisted in the browser. So `url` method is not required.

But because of this if you try to open the same in a different browser, you won't see any changes as the changes are are on the browser and not on the server.

Comment: The localstorage is only defined on the collection, how does the model know about it?

Comment: Correct. The collection takes a model as a parameter

Comment: So when the model is created as part of the collection, the adapter is initialized in the collection. So when you save the model, then adapter takes care of saving the model as that is part of the collection on which it is defined

Comment: @ChrisMuench.. glad to have helped :)